# Function returns different value when called inside a trigger function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers

I have a function in plpgsql which return the an integer value based on a selection criteria,
select using function returns the right value but return zero when called inside a trigger function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_value(companyid int) RETURNS INT AS
$$
DECLARE 
    currentindexnumber int;
BEGIN
    SELECT s.number INTO currentindexnumber 
    FROM table AS s 
    WHERE s.compid = get_index_value_sticker.companyid  
    ORDER BY s.id DESC 
    LIMIT 1;

    RETURN currentindexnumber;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```
Create OR REPLACE Function new_indexincreament() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $new_indexincreament_function$
 Declare
    newindex integer; 
 BEGIN
 
newindex := (SELECT get_index_value_sticker(new.compid))  + 1;

     
 update public.sticker set index = newindex where id = new.id;
 
 RETURN NEW;
     

END;
$new_indexincreament_function$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: That is what docs are for [Trigger Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html): 1) *A trigger function is created with the CREATE FUNCTION command, declaring it as a function with no arguments and a return type of trigger (for data change triggers) or event_trigger (for database event triggers).* 2)   *A trigger function must return either NULL or a record/row value having exactly the structure of the table the trigger was fired for.* 3) Please at least attempt to do the homework.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the function above is just an ordinary function that returns an integer value. when called outside a trigger it returns the desired value but within a trigger value is always zero.

Comment: something there is not right, shouldnt "INTO currentindexnumber " be at the end? like"    SELECT s.number
    FROM table AS s 
    WHERE s.compid = get_index_value_sticker.companyid  
    ORDER BY s.id DESC 
    LIMIT 1 INTO currentindexnumber ;" or something?

Comment: @LongBeard_Boldy already tried that same experience.

Comment: i dont get how "get_value(companyid int)" works for you at all, why input value "companyid int" declared, but not used, tehnicaly "SELECT s.number INTO currentindexnumber ..." should try to create a table named "currentindexnumber ", what exact;y is this part? " get_index_value_sticker.companyid  ", sholdnt it be "WHERE s.compid = companyid  "?

Comment: if you look carefully you see that the input value is been used but it's qualified with the name of the function. SQL server into works differently from postgresql. In postgresql function into is used for setting a variable instead of creating a table.

Comment: when trigger is called, before or after insert or update? is it called  FOR EACH ROW?

Comment: 1) Add the actual trigger definition to your question. 2) This `newindex := (SELECT get_index_value_sticker(new.compid))  + 1` can be simplified to `SELECT get_index_value_sticker(new.compid))  + 1 INTO newindex`.